# Integration by Recognition

Tags: integration, trigonometry

A question in my text book as ask me to investigate to relationship
$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{-2\cos xdx}{(1-\sin x)^2}$ shares with $
(\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x})
$

I have used integration by recognition to go about it showing that,

$
\dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}) = \dfrac{-2\cos x}{(1-\sin x)^2}
$

However, when I tried integrating $\dfrac{-2cosx}{(1-sinx)^2}$ I don't arrive back at $\dfrac{1+sinx}{1-sinx}$

So, how do you integrate  $\dfrac{-2\cos x}{(1-\sin x)^2}$?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**:Still go thru the traditional steps: $u = 1 - \sin x$ is the first step. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle I =  -\int\frac{2\cos x}{(1-\sin x)^2}dx\;,$$ Now Let $(1-\sin x) = t\;,$ Then $\cos dx = dt$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = -2\int\frac{1}{t^2}dt = \frac{2}{t}+\mathcal{C} = \frac{2}{(1-\sin x)}+\mathcal{C} = \frac{(1+\sin x)+(1-\sin x)}{(1-\sin x)}+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I =  \frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}+1+\mathcal{C} =  \frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}+\mathcal{C'}\;,$$ Where $\mathcal{C'} = 1+\mathcal{C}$

Comment: So the integral does come out to be $\dfrac{1+sinx}{1-sinx}$?

Comment: although original answer is $\displaystyle \frac{2}{1-\sin x}\;,$ But here we have to prove $\displaystyle \frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}.$ So our answer is $\displaystyle \frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}.$